# segmentation fault when return loss error during pytorch training

Tags: segmentation-fault, pytorch

I encountered a segmentation fault issue when return loss during training.
I use **gdb** to find out what's wrong, but only get the following lines:

```python
Epoch 0,    step 0,   Current loss 518.903503418
```

Thread 1 "**Python**" received signal **SIGSEGV**, Segmentation fault.

`_int_free (av=0x7ffff7bb4b20 <main_arena>, p=0xd767b30, have_lock=0)` at

```python
malloc.c:3841
3841

malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Then I debug the program line by line, and find out when return the loss, it would be broken.

The code snippets as following:

```python
class ContrastiveLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, margin=1):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__()
        self.margin = margin

    def forward(self, output1, output2, label):
        output1 = output1 / torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(output1, 2), 1).view(output1.size()[0], 1))
        output2 = output2 / torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(output2, 2), 1).view(output2.size()[0], 1))
        dist = torch.sum( torch.pow(output1 - output2, 2),1)
        dist_sq = torch.sqrt(dist)
        loss = (1-label) * dist + label * torch.pow(torch.clamp(self.margin - dist_sq, min=0.0), 2)
        loss = torch.sum(loss) / loss.size()[0]
        return loss
```

Any idea of what could cause it? 
It's interesting when calling the loss function firstly, it can run properly. But when calling it again, it will break.

Comment: Does the previous calculation (`loss = torch.sum(loss) / loss.size()[0]`) run okay? I'd check that each of the components of that calculation make sense, then that the `loss` variable you're returning makes sense. I can't think of any reason that you should get a segmentation fault from returning a Tensor.